# How to create Character based arrays in Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying some C++, but I'm too new to this and you can say that this is my first day at C++. So I was trying to create a function but I was stuck with arrays! When I create a Character based array like this :

```
char x[7][7] = {"sec","min","hr","day","week","month","year"};
```

And when I try to fetch the data from it like this :

```
for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
  cout << x[i] << "\n";    
}
```

I get some strange results! Like this :
[image]

Can anyone tell me where I'm going totally wrong! And please I'm new to C++ so can you provide me a good explanation.

Comment: Don't use Turbo C++. Use a modern IDE like Code::Blocks or VC++  Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have 7 values, and the array is indexed from 0, you only need to count up to 6, not 7.  Modify your `for` loop as `for (i=0;i < 7;i++)`.  (`<` instead of `<=`.)

You're going over the end of the array, which may give you garbage data or may just crash your program.

Comment: Thanks buddy I just overlooked somewhere and tried your `i<7&&My Other Statement` and it worked just as I thought!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i<=7;i++){
  cout << x[i] << "\n";    
}
```

The array indices will only range from `0` to `6`, and you check for `i<=7`. Change that to `i < 7`.

Comment: @Jack: Compare with `i<=6` if you need to use that.

Comment: Ok as you say. But this is not required for my code to work. I think I have to give up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in creating the array but in printing the results. Arrays in C, C++, Java, C#... and many other languages are 0 based. When you declare an array of 7 elements you iterate from 0 to 6:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i ) {
   std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Note: `<` and not a `<=`.